# Text Entry in Zenity

Tags: command-line, zenity

I am trying to do a delete function inside a zenity entry box .
I would like to know how can I store the path given by the user inside the entry box in a variable or how can I use it . Thanks. here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function Ddate() {
    zenity --info \
    --title "Date and Time" \
    --text "Today is $(date)"
}

function Dcalendar() {
    zenity --calendar \
    --title "Calendar"
}

function Ddelete() {    
    zenity --entry \
    --entry-text "Ex: home/knoppix/" \
    --text "Enter a path" \
    --title "Delete"
}

while true;
do
choice="$(zenity --height 275 --width 450 \
--list \
--title="Menu" \
--column="Function" --column="Description" \
    Date 'Display the actual date and time.' \
    Calendar 'Display an interactive calendar.' \
    Delete 'Let you delete a file.' \
    Exit 'To quit this script.')"

case $choice in
    Date) Ddate;;
    Calendar) Dcalendar;;
    Delete) Ddelete;;
    Exit) break;;

esac

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you want insert the data in a variable from "zenity" you can try this example :

```
NAME=$( zenity --entry --text="type your name" )

if [ $? = 0 ] # check if the user click ok on the zenity form
then
    echo "Hello $NAME"
else
    echo "the user didn't click ok button"
fi
```

I hope this helps.